# How can I build expression c=>c.workers.any(o=>o.code=='XXX' || c.name=='XXX') dynamically

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, expression

I learn how to build simple expression which like

```
c=>c.code=='XXX';
```

I create these expression by method below:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildStringEqualLambda(string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    ParameterExpression parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    Expression propertyExp = parameterExp;
    foreach (var property in propertyName.Split('.'))
    {
        propertyExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(propertyExp, property);
    }
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
    Expression e1 = Expression.Equal(propertyExp, right);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(e1, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExp });
}
```

I think I can build expression

```
o=>o.code=='XXX' || c.name=='XXX'
```

But I don't know how can I build method Any.

Thanks

Comment: take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730432/how-do-i-build-expression-call-for-any-method-with-generic-parameter

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildStringEqualLambda<T>(params Tuple<string, string>[] propertyNameValues)
{
    if (propertyNameValues == null || propertyNameValues.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(propertyNameValues));
    }

    ParameterExpression parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");

    Expression body = null;

    foreach (var propertyNameValue in propertyNameValues)
    {
        Expression propertyExp = parameterExp;

        foreach (var property in propertyNameValue.Item1.Split('.'))
        {
            propertyExp = Expression.PropertyOrField(propertyExp, property);
        }

        Expression right = Expression.Constant(propertyNameValue.Item2);
        Expression eq = Expression.Equal(propertyExp, right);

        body = body == null ? eq : Expression.OrElse(body, eq);
    }

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExp });
}
```

You can probably use some funny LINQ with `Aggregate` to reduce the number of lines, but it would be undebuggable.

In the end you use the `Expression.OrElse` (**not** the `Expression.Or` that is `|`!) and you handle the first element case.

Use it like:

```
var exp = BuildStringEqualLambda(
    Tuple.Create("prop1", "value1"),
    Tuple.Create("prop2", "value2"),
    Tuple.Create("prop3", "value3")
);
```

Using some LINQ and `Aggregate` (for those who can't live without LINQing everything) (note that while I wouldn't ever use the LINQed version of the code... It is quite unreadable... `Enumerable.Aggregate` is "terrible" ):

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildStringEqualLambda<T>(params Tuple<string, string>[] propertyNameValues)
{
    if (propertyNameValues == null || propertyNameValues.Length == 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(nameof(propertyNameValues));
    }

    ParameterExpression parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");

    Expression body = propertyNameValues
        .Select(x => BuildEqualityExpression<T>(parameterExp, x.Item1, x.Item2))
        .Aggregate((acc, x) => Expression.OrElse(acc, x));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, new ParameterExpression[] { parameterExp });
}

private static Expression BuildEqualityExpression<T>(ParameterExpression parameterExp, string propertyName, string propertyValue)
{
    Expression propertyExp = propertyName
        .Split('.')
        .Aggregate((Expression)parameterExp, (acc, x) => Expression.PropertyOrField(acc, x));

    Expression right = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
    Expression eq = Expression.Equal(propertyExp, right);
    return eq;
}
```